# WAMP Server: Website doesn't show on other's PC like how on mine via ip address

Tags: wordpress, layout, graphics, wamp

I created a local website using WAMP and Wordpress, which looks great on my PC.  However, when others try to access it, they only get the text, with no graphics or layout like on my PC.  Also, since my PC uses a local domain name, if others click on a link it goes nowhere.  Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Thank you

Comment: It would probably be a good starting point to post your HTML as well as a link to your site.

Comment: Locally it's kin.alexanderwang.com
Externally, it's 192.168.3.96

Answer (score 1):

get them to add the following line to their hosts file:

`kin.alexanderwang.com 192.168.3.96`

this will define that url as a hostname of that ip for any Windows machine you add to the hosts file (which is in windows/system32/drivers/etc/ or something like that).  that should resolve the link issue which is probably what is breaking your layout / images.

also note that is a network IP address so people outside your lan will not be able to access it.

Comment: OK, I understand, but is there a way to set it up so anyone can use it without having to customize their host file?  Would I have to setup a DNS.  This is for an office so I can ask out network manager for help on this.

Comment: It's most likely possible but depends on your router and network settings and is probably quite a bit more work than it really needs to be particularly if your office network isn't already configured for "real" intranet.  It's probably more trouble than it's worth... it would be a lot more simple (and quick) to just upload it to a web server temporarily.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I spoke to them and we will have to setup a time to do it, since the server would be bad if we had to restart it during office hours.